# add 2dsphere index for all documents in mongoDB collection

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I have a mongoDB table with long/lat as fields. I need to add a 2dsphere index based on the values of those fields to a collection. What is the best way to update all documents in the collection?

Answer (score 0):

With documents like this?

```
> db.test.findOne()
{ "_id" : 0, "lat" : 45.2, "lon" : 37.5 }
```

In the mongo shell, try this for the update

```
> db.test.find().forEach(function(doc) {
    var geo = { "type" : "Point", "coordinates" : [doc.lon, doc.lat] }
    db.test.update({ "_id" : doc._id }, { "$set" : { "loc" : geo }, "$unset" : { "lat" : true, "lon" : true } })
})
```

Now create the geo index:

```
> db.test.ensureIndex({ "loc" : "2dsphere" })
```